# Less installation on macOS

Tags: macos, npm, terminal, less, npm-install

I have installed less using

```
npm install -g less
```

and then I installed less-watch-compiler

```
npm install -g less-watch-compiler
```

but when I try to run

```
less-watch-compiler
```

using less-watch-compiler.config.json file 
it tells me that 
(command not found)

```
lessc file.less
```

tells me the same too

I tried many things but nothing works.
I am using macOS Mojave and npm version is 6.4.1

Comment: What command did you run?

Comment: less-watch-compiler
with less-watch-compiler.config.json

Answer (score 1):

**Problem Solve**

I used instructions here to show the hidden folders [how to show hidden files in macOS](https://ianlunn.co.uk/articles/quickly-showhide-hidden-files-mac-os-x-mavericks/)

then I opened the .bash_profile file from /Users/(user) and added this line to the end

```
PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.npm-global/bin"
export PATH
```

this added the two commands lessc and less-watch-compiler